# Dynamic notifications using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, jgrowl

I'm currently building a homepage for our staff which is to be set as the homepage in their browser. I'm currently building the facility whereby nominated members of staff can send notifications to all staff. These will popup on their home page without the need for them to refresh the page.

I've currently got the code below which worked fine for 1 notification, but there may be more than 1 at a time waiting to be shown. I've switched to outputting json but I'm not sure how to modify my code to consume it.

I'm using the PeriodicalUpdater and jGrowl plugins to get this functionality, if there's better alternatives then feel free to sugget them.

```
    $.PeriodicalUpdater({
        url: 'getNotifications.aspx',
        maxTimeout: 6000,
        type: 'json'
    },
    function(data) {
        var message = data;
        if (message != '') {
            $.jGrowl(message, { sticky: true });
        }
    });
```

As an additional piece of functionality, would it be possible to store in a cookie when a user has closed a notification so they don't see it again?

Thanks.

---

OK, I've updated the code so that it's now;

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var alreadyGrowled = new Array();

        var growlCheckNew = function() {
            $.getJSON('getNotifications.aspx', function(data) {
                $(data).each(function(entryIndex,entry) {
                    var newMessage = true;
                    $(alreadyGrowled).each(function(index,msg_id) {
                        if (entry['ID'] == msg_id) {
                            newMessage = false;
                        }
                    });

                    if (newMessage == true) {
                        $.jGrowl(entry['Message'], {
                            sticky: true,
                            header: entry['Title'],
                            beforeClose: function(e,m) {
                                alert('About to close this message');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    alreadyGrowled.push(entry['ID']);
                });
            });
        }

        growlCheckNew();

        var msgTimer = setInterval(growlCheckNew, 1000);

    });
```

However, my alerts not firing when I close a growl notification?! I've got that in there to check it works before putting some code in to save it to a cookie. Does this look about right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can output all the messages as a list in the JSON output and simply iterate over the message list in javascript.

JSON output:

```
{
    messages:['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']
}
```

javascript:

```
$.PeriodicalUpdater({
    url: 'getNotifications.aspx',
    maxTimeout: 6000,
    type: 'json'
},
function(data) {
    for(message in data.messages) {
        $.jGrowl(message, { sticky: true });
    }
});
```

Comment: Should've mentioned this originally. How would it work if I'm outputting two objects in json; Title and Message?

Comment: so each notification has a title and a message body? you can do that by outputting a list of objects instead of a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

As for the cookie problem, you could use [the jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) for that.

Syntax:

```
// To set a cookie ‘foo’ with value 'bar':
$.cookie('foo', 'bar');
// To get the value stored in a cookie:
$.cookie('foo'); // 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation we used a rss file running on an IIS backend with a free tool to edit the .xml. We then used an rss widget to display the latest news, some people used an rss reader and others used Outlook as well.

Quick and simple.